# Enable PHP in Smarty

Tags: smarty

We're using software based on smarty. However we can't use PHP in the smarty templates as it has been disabled in /includes/libs/smarty/ for security reasons. The directory is unencrypted. How can we still enable PHP?

Thanks!

Kind Regards,

Sander

Answer (score 2):

The php tag is disabled by default, you can enable it by yourself:

> The {php} tag is disabled by default. Enable with $smarty->allow_php_tag=true.

Answer (score 1):

If it has been disabled by way of security policy, and you have no way to overwrite that policy (because it's encrypted or some such), you're shit out of luck.

Besides {php} being deprecated (and thus removed in the future), the "proper way" to integrate PHP into your templates is by registering the necessary functions as smarty plugins. See [registerPlugin()](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl) for that.

But if you're not able to overwrite the security policy, I doubt you'll be able to register custom plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The developer however replied to me with this: "Library is unencrypted, you can enable it. We don't provide support for this.". So, it should be possible I guess.